# How and where to register a desk-band in the registry?

Tags: c#, c++, shell, windows-7-x64, taskbar

Prior to this question, I asked this one:

1. [How to add a form to Windows 7 taskbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40438889/how-to-add-a-form-to-windows-7-taskbar)

I tried with the Code Project source code, which I can't make it work on the Windows Shell Taskbar either.

2. [Extending Explorer with Band Objects using .NET and Windows Forms](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/2219/extending-explorer-with-band-objects-using-net-and)

I also tried using the EZShellExtensions.NET library trial, which seems to work fine with Internet Explorer, but I can't have it on the Windows Shell.

3. [EZShellExtensions.Net v2013](http://www.ssware.com/ezshell/ezshell.htm)

Then, there's this GitHub native code in C++ which I gave a try by downloading and compiling it, and it doesn't look like it works either.

4. [Windows-classic-samples/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/shellextensibility/deskbands/](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/winui/shell/shellextensibility/deskbands)

Notice that when implementing the IDeskBand interface, I did implement the IDeskBand2 as well because I need it to work on Windows 7.

Any other useful information may be provided upon request since I really don't know what to provide as useful information other than what is already in.

I know there's a slight difference between an ExplorerBar and a ToolBar, and that is where to register it. I've been working on this for days, I just can't make it.

So, **where to register a desk-band in the registry to make it appear as a Toolbar option in the Taskbar contextual menu of Windows 7?**

Comment: you shouldn't be using .net for shell extensions.

Comment: @DanielA.White: I don't mind to use either .NET or native C++, as long as it works. Both ways are feasible, according to the articles provided in the link with the question's body. Besides, starting from .NET 4, since more than one CLR can be loaded side by side, it is doable in .NET, although not recommended. In the end, the fourth link states being native C++ code, and it doesn't do much good either.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: I don't care. I need to do it per customer's request. It's doable, and I wanna do it.

Comment: i vaguely remember microsoft removing support for these in windows 7

Comment: @DanielA.White [it looks like it is still supported](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd378460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#deskbands), just that they want you to use thumbnail toolbar where possible instead.